# How does this module know about the data in another module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My understanding of modules is that they are distinct from each other. However I don't understand why this code works then.

Lets say I have three files in the node.js framework. One "app.js" driver file and two modules:

Module "one.js" simply has a property called "name":

```
module.exports = {

    name: null

}
```

Module "two.js" loads module "one.js" and declares a function that prints out the contents of the property "name" in the "one.js" module:

```
var one = require('./one');

module.exports = {

    printname: function()
    {
        console.log(one.name);
    }

}
```

Now the driver (app.js) imports both modules, sets the property of the first module, then calls the name printing function of the second:

```
var one = require("./one");
var two = require("./two");

two.printname();

one.name = "John";

two.printname();
```

When I run this, it prints "null" (fine, it should be empty), then "John" (not fine). How is the second module learning of the value in the first module?

My thought process is: when "two.js" loads its own version of "one.js", the property "name" should always be null. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying a property of an `Object`, and Objects are passed by reference, therefore all the instances that imported `one.js` got the same instance.

If you need different instances you should export a `class` and create an instance on demand.

Something like that:

```
//one.js
class Data {
   constructor(data) {
      this.data = data;
   }
}
export.module = Data;

//two.js
const Data = require('./one');
const data = new Data('John');
```

Answer (score 1):

`one`'s export is a static object. It it not `new` every time.

You can change it like so:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return { name: null }
}
```

Then:

```
var one = require("./one");

var willAlwaysBeNew = one();
willAlwaysBeNew.name = "john"

var willAlwaysBeNewToo = one();

console.log(willAlwaysBeNew.name) // john
console.log(willAlwaysBeNewToo.name) // null
```